# Flash game and animation

Tags: flash, animation

I'm helping a friend create a small flash game (working in AS) and the basic features are:
 - you have a piano , some bottles and a glass 
 - each key (on the piano) represents a different bottle of alcohol
 - when a key is pressed the bottle will pour in the glass,

There general idea is that by playing the piano you create a cocktail.

I know how to animate each object. What I want to know is how use those animations and trigger them with an action listener.

In Unity3D, which I am fluent in, you create an animation in 3dsmax and a model, you import them to Unity3d and when your character simply walks, it uses the animation walk(made in 3dsmax). When you hit "space" lets say, it uses the animation jump and so on.

How would I accomplish something like this in AS?

Meaning create animations first, save them and use them in another project which will be the game, or in the same project.

Hope you understood if not, I will answer any misunderstandings.

Comment: How much actionscript do you know right now?  Everything you described is easily accomplished in actionscript but altogether it is a lot of concept. ARe you interested in learning how to DESIGN such a project or how to IMPLEMENT specifics like creating key listener triggered animations/actions and such?

Answer (score 1):

There are sometimes many ways to achieve your goals in Flash. I'll talk about one of them for your project. I won't give you everything you'll need but you'll at least have a general idea of what to do and what terms to search for.

The basic idea in Flash is that you can separate things by MovieClips which are kind of like Prefabs in Unity. A MovieClip has its own timeline which you may use to control all visuals (including nested MovieClips) within that MovieClip. These MovieClips may be told by any code to Play(), Stop(), gotoAndPlay(Frame#) etc. to completely control which portions of that MovieClip's timeline to play.

You could create several different animations using different parts of the timeline which all use your bottle graphic. One portion could be a looping animation for sitting there bubbling or something. Another portion could be the actually pouring/tipping, another continuous pouring, and another for stop pouring/untipping. Then you could add frame labels on another layer to help you manage them, and actions like stop or 'repeat' on yet another layer such that the animations will loop or stop when they reach the end of their segment.

Once your animations are created and you can invoke them with code, such as gotoAndPlay("pouring") then you can worry about EventListeners. An EventListener will invoke a function you've made every time something happens. If you make an EventListener for Key Press then you will need to check for the specific key which was pressed within the function you write. Depending on the key then you will invoke different animations and possibly other functions such as making a note sound, liquid pouring sound, and keeping track of "how much" the user is pouring. It is usually useful to make a listener for key press down and key press up.

You can copy MovieClips you've made in your library between projects simply by dragging and dropping between projects. It is sometimes useful to use folders in your library to help organize things especially when you are copying between projects.

Search for tutorials and practice new things in a new project to reduce complexity until you are sure how it works and how to use it.

Multiple Animations

If you are animating on the timeline and have different animations you want to play on different layers in that timeline, then you must separate the animations not only by layer, but horizontally in time as well. Add a new layer for labels. Add a new layer for stop actions. Create a frame label in the labels layer at the beginning of each animation segment. Add a stop command in the actions layer at the end of each animation. Now that you have start and stop points defined by labels and actions, it's time to invoke them using code. Now you may reference that movieclip containing your animations/layers and use the gotoAndPlay("framelabelhere") command to play a certain animation.

The drawback here is that your animations are mutually exclusive, meaning they must share the same timeline and thus you can only have 1 playing at a time. If you need concurrency, then instead separate your animations by movieclips; each movieclip will have its own timeline and so can play independently. In the latter case you may use myMovieClipInstanceNameHere.play() to start the timeline playing. You may need initial stop commands in the timeline to make sure they don't play by default.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your insight , i think i'm going to try and place each object on a layer and animate them using motion tween, my question now is can i use them in actionscript to choose which animation to play based on the current event and where do i write the code , do i create a new actionscript file and write the whole code in there or do i have to use actions on different layers, and what type should my objects be,can i use them as motion clips even though i used motion tween ?

Comment: Updated my answer to include details on playing multiple animations.